# How to manage quartz Schedulars

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have designed a framework to send alerts in the form of email based on a search filter. This is handled by a quartz job. per each alert there is a criteria associated with it. Currently it is maintained by a single job. As the no of criteria increases, the no.of tasks that need to be done by this job also increases. Is there a better way to manage this job. Please note that, these criteria are created dynamically. So I can use only a single job and I need a way to handle it.

Comment: This depends on how you have designed your task execution. As scheduler runs every x minutes, if you can design your system only to get new filters for x minutes it would be efficient. 

But if you really need to consider all the filters in every x minutes you need to have multiple triggers and need to design it properly to process data dividing dataset among multiple triggers based on timestamp or some sequencing.

Comment: I need to consider all filters. These filters provides the required information to be included in the email content and this information varies dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple triggers for one Quartz job. In the data associated with the trigger you can add your criteria. This way a single job can do dynamically different things.

Comment: If possible, can you provide a link where I can check for some examples

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. If you want to save time creating and maintaining your own monitoring and notification framework, you may want to check our project [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) that is a generic platform that allows you manage and monitor your Quartz jobs/triggers in all types of Java applications.

In QuartzDesk GUI you can create [notification rules](https://www.quartzdesk.com/documentation/features#notification-rules) with arbitrary conditions that send a notification message over the configured SMTP (email), instant message, SNMP Trap or web-service message channel. You can be notified of any situation that occurs during your job's execution including job execution status, duration, result etc. You can even analyze the intercepted log data produced by your job and send a notification message in case the log contains particular data.

Comment: Thanks.... But I am looking for an open source... and the operations should be done at background.

Comment: If you are after an open-source solution, you may want to check JWatch (https://code.google.com/p/jwatch/). It does not seem to be maintained (latest release was in 2011), but maybe you could extract and reuse some code...